# How to get InnerHTML value from Xpath Result

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I have the following Xpath that I can retrieve the StringValue from; however, I need to get the actual inner.HTML value so that I can parse at the new line. How would I go about doing this?

```
var html = '<table><tbody><tr><td width="33%">SMITH WILLIAM  <br>SMITH TOM  <br>501 NW 3ND ST<br>CHICAGO IL 60073</td></tr></tbody></table>';


var Xpath = '//table/tbody/tr/td[1]'; 
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html,'text/html');
result = doc.evaluate(Xpath, doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
alert('Xpath Result:' + result.stringValue); //NEED HTML i.e. HTML.Value
```

Current Outcome: `SMITH WILLIAM  SMITH TOM  501 NW 3ND STCHICAGO IL 60073`

Desired Outcome: `SMITH WILLIAM  <br>SMITH TOM  <br>501 NW 3ND ST<br>CHICAGO IL 60073`

Comment: Can you post the html you're working with and your desired output?

Comment: SHouldn't `XPathResult.STRING_TYPE` be set to a node type? Been awhile since I worked with this.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `propertyOwners.stringValue` instead of `result.stringValue`?

Comment: sorry Tim, that was a typo, the value has been changed to 'result.stringValue.'

Comment: For future reference, it's helpful to make sure the code in your question is enough for someone to run (in this case, I get an error that `parser` isn't defined), and for a question like this it'd be good to have a minimal example of the html you're running it against.  That way, we can actually test out our answers.  But, I posted an answer based on what I *think* you want, which I tested against this page with `'//div[@id="question-header"]'` as the `xpathExpression`.

Comment: `var parser = new DOMParser();`

Comment: Glad my answer helped you!  I went ahead and cleaned up your question a bit more: making it runnable by defining `parser` and `html`, including the output you had been getting (to help illustrate the difference between that and what you wanted), and simplifying the XPath expression so it works with the example HTML you gave us (which you rightly made a simplified version of your actual HTML).  Following this example will help your next question avoid downvotes, hopefully :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the result type a node type, then you can get the innerHTML from the node.  For example:

```
var result = document.evaluate(xpathExpression, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
alert('Xpath Result:' + result.singleNodeValue.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you Tim! Greatly appreciate the extra effort. I will be sure to include supporting code going forward.